# Solve a particular case of the Lyapunov equation for infinite dimensional matrices

Tags: tensor-calculus, linear-systems

Consider the matrix Lyapunov-type equation

$BX + XB = \partial_R B^{-1}$

where $B$ is a (known) symmetric square matrix which depends parametrically on $R$. Can we find a  *symmetric* matrix $X$ which solves the equation?

I am aware of the existence of the vectorization operation, but this is near-useless for me  as my matrices are infinite-dimensional and thus cannot be inverted using a computer. What I'm ideally after is a closed-form expression for the components $X_{ij}$ given $B_{ij}(R)$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand why it is unclear. As I said, I'm looking for the matrix $X_{ij}$ which solves the equation above given $B_{ij}(R)$

Comment: There appears to be very little physics in this. Have you tried MSE? You might use lower case *r* for your parameter, and write your equation in canonical form, $X+ B^{-1} X B= -\partial_r B ~B^{-1}$.

Comment: The Lyapunov equation appears in the study of many dynamical systems, and infinite-dimensional matrices come from eigenfunction expansions which are rarely addressed in pure mathematics (indeed, I've tried in the Math section of SE as well). I am a Physicist and I found this equation on my way, I could give more physical background but it wouldn't add anything to the question.

Comment: The solution will depend on the peculiar nature of $B(r)$ and its gradient.